# Taking Average of List of Integers

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, sum, average

I'm scraping a list of daily stock volume numbers, and I'm wanting to take an average of the first 20 results in the volume column of the page. My code looks like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re, csv, random, time
import pandas as pd
import os
import requests

    page = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BDSI/history?period1=1517033117&period2=1548569117&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    rows = soup.select('table[class="W(100%) M(0)"] tr')

    for row in rows[1:20]:
        col = row.find_all("td")
        numbers = col[6].text.replace(',', '')
        numbers2 = int(numbers)
        print(numbers2)

        avg20vol = sum(numbers2(1,20))/len(numbers2)
```

...but I'm getting stuck when trying to take the average of the returned numbers2. Receive either "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" or "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" with the solutions I've tried. How do handle taking an average of a list? Does it involve turning it into a dataframe first? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here's a working example of the applicable code segment:

```
    numberslist=[]

    for row in rows[1:21]:
        col = row.find_all("td")
        numbers = col[6].text.replace(',', '')
        numbers2 = int(numbers)
        numberslist.append(numbers2)
        print(numbers2)
        average = sum(numberslist)/len(numberslist)


    print('Average = ',average)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When scraping, actually create a list of numbers, like so:

```
# stuff before

number_list = []  # empty list

for row in rows[1:20]:
    # get the number
    number_list.append(int(number_as_string))  # add the new number at the end of the list

average = sum(number_list)/len(number_list)
```

You can also `.append()` the string forms and then transform to `int`s with `list(map(int(list_of_strings))` or `[int(x) for x in list_of_strings]`.

Note: `rows[1:20]` will leave out the first item, in your case, as you stated, the first row is header. Use `rows[:20]` to get the first 20 items in general.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. I'll update with my answer code. Oh, and the first row seems to be the header row as 1 does start on the first day, but I did update it to [1:21] to make sure it got the last 20 days, not 19 using [1:20]. Thanks!

Comment: @MattWilson great it worked. I'll update my answer, wasn't thinking about header rows

Answer (score 1):

You css selector is also wrong and gave me an error.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BDSI/history?period1=1517033117&period2=1548569117&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.find('table',class_="W(100%) M(0)").find_all('tr')
numbers=[]
for row in rows[1:20]:
    col = row.find_all("td")
    print(col[6].text)
    number = col[6].text.replace(',', '')
    number = int(number)
    numbers.append(number)

avg20vol =sum(numbers)/len(numbers)
print("Average: ",avg20vol)
```

Output

```
650,100
370,500
374,700
500,700
452,500
1,401,800
2,071,200
1,005,800
441,500
757,000
901,200
563,400
1,457,000
637,100
692,700
725,000
709,000
1,155,500
496,400
Average:  808584.2105263158
```